# Gson cannot serialize/deserialize dates correctly

Tags: java, gson

It is weird that the following test case would fail. Anybody knows why?

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS")
    .create();
Date date = new Date();
String json = gson.toJson(date);
System.out.println(date);
Date date2 = gson.fromJson(json, Date.class);
System.out.println(date2);
assertEquals(date2, date);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of some data loss and the default `java.util.Date` constructor is milliseconds-sensitive, but the default Gson date/time format configuration (and you're probably using it) ignores milliseconds. Just compare to make sure:

```java
System.out.println(date.getTime());
System.out.println(date2.getTime());
```

The default Gson date/time serializer (not deserializer) format is `DateTimeAdapter.enUsFormat` (as of Gson 2.8.0) that does not include milliseconds to date JSON representations. To overcome this this behavior, you just have to define a pattern that would respect all time values including milliseconds:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS")
        .create();
```

#### Update #1

There was a typo. `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS` works from 00:00 to 11:59 inclusively, but fails from 12:00 to 23:59. I tested it in the morning, so I didn't notice I was wrong. :) A more accurate format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` -- `HH` denotes an hour in range of 00..23:

```
.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```